# "Которые" или "которых"?

Tags: согласование, падежи

> Чем выше вязкость плазмы, тем больше плотность эритроцитов, котор**ые**(**-ых**) она удерживает в вихревой упаковке.

Ответы на аналогичные вопросы не дали четкого представления, какой вариант выбрать. Мне кажется, что это может зависеть от одушевленности/неодушевленности. Например, *"зайцев, котор**ые** она удерживает"* не скажешь, а с эритроцитами наоборот.
Если можно, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылки на правила, а то мне говорят: "Эритроцитов каких? - котор**ых**" (и всё тут!), но ведь здесь дело не в этом, потому что может быть и такой случай: "Эритроцитов каких? - с котор**ыми**".
На Грамоте.ру нашел такой ответ: *"Верно: выйти на участки, которых они обычно избегают"*.

Comment: А *плазма* своей одушевленностью *удерживает*?

Comment: @shampar Нет, конечно.

Comment: Ибегают чего (р. п.), а она удерживает что (в. п.).

Comment: @РоманКорнеев Уровень книг, которые она читает... Уровень детей, которых она учит. То есть в вашем случае вопрос будет задаваться от глагола в придаточном: удерживает (которые?) или удерживает (которых?)? Если так, то мой ответ неверен (удалю его) и вопрос действительно сводится к одушевлённости/неодушевлённости.
Что касается правил одушевлённости/неодушевлённости винительного падежа, то они описаны тут: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_08

Comment: Спасибо всем! Да, всё правильно. Конечно, слово "который" в винительном падеже зависит от одушевленности. Викисловарь: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: @shampar тут, как я понял, дело не в одушевлённости удерживающего, а в  одушевлённости удерживаемого. Пять зайцев, которых удерживает ловушка. Пять мотоциклов, которые удерживает ловушка.

Comment: Пять зайцев, которые удерживаются ловушкой. (Пример неодушевлённых удерживаемых.)

Comment: @shampar во-первых, в вашем случае удерживаемые всё равно зайцы (а ловушка — удерживающая). Во-вторых, в случае возвратного глагола вообще разницы нет, удерживается неодушевлённое или одушевлённое. Пять зайцев, которые удерживаются дамой в вуали. Потому что разница возникает только в винительном падеже, а в случае возвратного глагола падеж именительный: удерживаются кто/что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Чем выше вязкость плазмы, тем больше плотность эритроцитов, **которые** (В.п) она удерживает в вихревой упаковке.*

**Это чистая грамматика:** падеж союзному слову КОТОРЫЕ в придаточном определительном предложении задает глагол в придаточном предложении. Удерживает (что?) эритроциты.

Сравнить: *Выйти на участки, **которых** (Р. п.) они обычно избегают.* Избегают (чего?) участков.

Из словаря:

УДЕРЖАТЬ, св. **кого-что**. Держа, поддерживая, не дать упасть кому-, чему-л. У. штангу. У. падающую сумку. У. руками. С трудом у. в руках. У. в равновесии

ИЗБЕГАТЬ,  нсв. **кого-чего** или с инф. 1. Сторониться кого-, чего-л., намеренно уклоняться от чего-л. И. соседа, знакомых, друг друга.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Разобрались уже.

Comment: Пожалуйста, но  я не читала ответов, просто это  основной принцип построения придаточных предложений этого вида. А почему тогда ни один из ответов не был оформлен? Вот я и не знала, что уже разобрались.

Comment: Был один ответ от Nektoid, но он его удалил. А разобрались по комментариям, в том числе под его ответом.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно.